# SPI Display – fbtft connects to wrong frame buffer

Tags: display, spi, lcd, framebuffer

Today I installed an SPI display to my pi. I'm using `fbtft` and follow the wiki. I don't want screen mirroring, but force the SPI display to be a secondary monitor.

I discovered, that fbtft connects to `/dev/fb0` instead of `fb1`. I'm guessing that `/etc/modules-load.d/fbtft.conf` gets loaded too early, since even when I have an HDMI monitor connected it occupies the first frame buffer and thus lets me end up with the HD HDMI monitor as secondary display...

Here the configuration:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/fbtft.conf
options fbtft_device name=fb_st7735r custom gpios=reset:27,dc:25,cs:8,led:24 speed=40000000 bgr=1 fps=60 height=128 width=128 rotate=90

# /etc/modules-load.d/fbtft.conf
spi-bcm2835
fbtft_device
```

It's strange, but I seem not be able to find other people with this issue. Any idea on why that happens or what I could do?